# Check that text field has text when clicking a link

Tags: javascript, jquery

(Hope the title of the question makes sense--not quite sure how to word this one).

I've been using a certain script to make sure that the CONTINUE/SUBMIT button is enabled so long as *at least one* of the text fields (all with the same class) has a value in it.  Here is that script (.donation corresponds to the text fields, .continue is the submit button):

```
var inputs = $('.donation').on('keyup', function() {
    $('.continue').prop('disabled', !(this.value.length || inputs.filter(function() {
        return $.trim(this.value).length > 0;
    }).length));
});
```

This works well, however I've created the option for users to be able to delete text fields using the following code. When the link with the class .dr is clicked, it deletes the text field from the page:

```
<a href="#" class="dr" title="Remove" onClick="return false;"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove-circle"></span></a>

$(".dr").live("click", function (){
    $(this).parent().parent().fadeOut( 1000, function() { 
        $(this).remove();
    });
});
```

**THE PROBLEM:** I can put a value into a text field and that activates the submit button as it should. However, if I then delete that textfield using the link, the submit button doesn't become disabled--it's still enabled.

I know that this is because the first script is looking for the keyup function in the .donation fields, and when I delete the field, it's obviously not invoking that.

So how do I fix it so that when I click the link, it checks the value of the text fields?

I tried creating a function that was called when .dr is clicked:

```
function checkDonation() {
    if ( inputs.val().length == 0 ) {
        $('.continue').prop('disabled', true);
    }
}
```

However, it only checks to see if the first text field is empty or not, and it seems to break the first script as it no longer checks the value of the text field when I enter characters.

Hope this makes sense and that you understand my problem. I'm still new to Javascript and Jquery. Thanks for your time!

**JSFiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/1c5r5Lef/

Comment: What version of `jQuery` are you using? `.live()` has been deprecated for ages.

Comment: Have you tried: `$(document).on("click", ".dr", function () {...`

Comment: @MelanciaUK - 1.9.1, I think. .live() has been working fine, but I'll try .on(). :)

Comment: Then you should use `.on()` instead.

Comment: I put in .on(), thanks for keeping me up to date! Unfortunately, though, this doesn't solve my problem with getting verification of the text field when clicking .dr.

Comment: The same here: `$(document).on('keyup', '.donation', function() { ...`

Comment: Create a `jsFiddle` to show us exactly what's going on.

Comment: @MelanciaUK - Here it is: http://jsfiddle.net/1c5r5Lef/
You'll see that the submit button is enabled when at least one field has text in it--so that works. But if I only enter text into a single field and then delete that field (hitting REMOVE), the submit button is still enabled. I need it to become disabled again when that happens.

Comment: Your `jsFiddle` is throwing an exception because you're still using `.live()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's a good case to use event delegation, and the 'value!=""' selector. You can see it here http://jsfiddle.net/cec9ybyx/

Event Delegation:

```
$( window ).on( 'keyup' , function( e )  {
    var target = $( e.target );
    if( target.is( '.donation' ) )
        toggleButton();    
});

$( window ).on( 'click' , function( e )  {
    var target = $( e.target );
    if( target.is( '.remove' ) )
        removeInput( e.target );
    else if( target.is( '#add' ) )
        addInput();
});
```

Remove Action:

```
function removeInput( obj ){
    $( obj ).parent().remove();
    toggleButton();
}
```

Toggle Action:

```
function toggleButton(){
    button.prop( 'disabled' , $( 'input.donation[value!=""]' ).length == 0 );
}
```

Comment: You don't need to check for the event target. It's a waste to attach the click event handler to the whole window and test which element has received the event. Just use the delegation mode as it is.

Answer (score 0):

This might work. try triggering the key up event when you remove the element

```
$(".dr").on("click", function (){
    $(this).parent().parent().fadeOut( 1000, function() { 
        $(this).remove();
        $('.donation').trigger('keyup')
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your method of checkDonation is a good approach, you could call it after removing the element. However, you'd need to check all inputs in order to see if there's a donation or not. I've tinkered a bit the method:

```
function checkDonation() {
    $('.continue').prop('disabled', true);
    $("input").each(function () {
        if ($(this).val().length !== 0) {
            console.log("One is not empty, reactivating.");
            $('.continue').prop('disabled', false);
            return false;
        }
    });
}
```

Calling this method would imply checking all inputs (maybe you could use a class instead of input to restrict the search and not include other inputs that the page could have). First, we disable the continue button. If any input contains value, we re-enable it and immediately return (we don't need to keep searching, one is condition enough).

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You have a few issues here.

Your HTML markup has various elements sharing the same `id`, which is invalid. Use a `class` instead if you want to manipulate all of them in the same way.

You were using `.live()` which is deprecated since v1.3 and has been removed since v1.7 of `jQuery`. Use `.on()` instead.

That's how I would do that:

```js
$(function() {
  // Check when page is loaded.
  checkInputs();

  function checkInputs() {
    var disabled = true;

    // If any input has a value, don't disable the button.
    $('.donation').each(function() {
      if ($(this).val()) {
        disabled = false;
      }
    });

    $('.continue').prop('disabled', disabled);
  }

  // On typing the text, check the inputs.
  $(document).on('keyup', '.donation', checkInputs);

  $(document).on('click', '.dr', function() {
    // Remove the row.
    $(this).parents('.cart-row').fadeOut(1000, function() {
      $(this).remove();

      // Check the inputs.
      checkInputs();
    });
  });
});
```

```css
.cart-row {
  overflow: auto;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #f5f5f5;
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
  width: 95%;
  margin: auto auto;
}
.form-left {
  width: 20%;
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 5%;
}
.form-name {
  padding-top: 5px;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  width: 70%;
}
.form-remove {
  padding-top: 5px;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  width: 5%;
  color: #b30f16;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <div class="cart-row">
    <div class="form-left">
      <div class="input-group">
        <span class="input-group-addon">$</span>
        <input type="text" id="fhaf" name="" class="donation form-control" placeholder="0.00" maxlength="15" />
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-name">Item 1</div>
    <div class="form-remove">
      <a href="#" class="dr" title="Remove Fund">REMOVE</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="cart-row">
    <div class="form-left">
      <div class="input-group">
        <span class="input-group-addon">$</span>
        <input type="text" id="fmf" name="" class="donation form-control" placeholder="0.00" maxlength="15" />
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-name">Item 2</div>
    <div class="form-remove">
      <a href="#" class="dr" id="donation" title="Remove Fund">REMOVE</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="cart-row">
    <div class="form-left">
      <div class="input-group">
        <span class="input-group-addon">$</span>
        <input type="text" id="fpef" name="" class="donation form-control" placeholder="0.00" maxlength="15" />
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-name">Item 3</div>
    <div class="form-remove">
      <a href="#" class="dr" title="Remove Fund">REMOVE</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <br />
  <br />
  <input type="submit" class="continue btn btn-primary" onClick="return false;" disabled="disabled" value="Continue »" />
</form>
```

[Demo jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MelanciaUK/1c5r5Lef/10/)